# Deploy .Net website project to Local Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, intranet

This is my first project with .Net so don't know how to compile / package the project for deployment. It is a Intranet site and will run on a internal MS Server 2012.  The server already has IIS and SQL express, I have tested a single page asp file in the wwwroot directory and that works fine. I am wondering how do I deploy my actual app to the server?

Would I have to change the connection strings (currently using localdb).
Also do the code behind files have to be somehow compiled?

Is it a case of copying and pasting the project files on server wwwroot directory?

Comment: Google how to "Publish" from Visual Studio. Just pasting the project files won't work, you need build it and then deploy the right files from the build. The publish tool makes that quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

its much easier with visual studio with few clicks.

Quick steps are:

1. Run visual Studio as Administrator
2. Right click on solution and deploy.
3. then configure Deployment profile.
4. Press Publish

for more info please check below URL.
https://support.winhost.com/kb/a1287/how-to-deploy-visual-studio-2013-web-application-project-to-winhost-server-using-web-deploy-ftp.aspx

After you deploy Go to wwwroot and find your application.Then copy these files to the remote server wwwroot/yourwebapplicationname

> you have to change the connection string matching to the server remote
>   server.